# IoT - Databricks Deltalake - access in C# api or Node js API

Tags: azure-blob-storage, iot, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am working on IoT solution, where there are multiple sensors which are sending data. I have one job which listen to Event hub, get the IoT sensor data and store in in Delta lake table. (Underlying Azure ADLS Gen-2 Storage in parquet file format)

I have to display the sensor data on UI (custom UI - developed in React). For that, I have API layer developed in .NET core API / Node JS API.

So finally I have to query Delta table created in data bricks to retrieve the sensor data - using Node JS / .NET CORE and display it on UI. How I can query the data from C# / Node JS API from delta lake table?

Comment: what is the ask?

Comment: Updated question above. How I can query the data from C# / Node JS API from delta lake table?

Comment: [Can a .NET C# application connect and query from an Azure Databricks or Azure Synapse Spark Delta Lake table?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/340847/can-a-net-c-application-connect-and-query-from-an.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using query compute that already is capable of reading the delta formatted data. A low cost option would be to create an Azure Synapse Analytics workspace and use a serverless SQL pool to query the delta content. A serverless pool exposes itself as an Azure SQL DB. So, any tool that can query an Azure SQL DB (not a problem for either C# or node.js) can then query those delta tables.

The SQL syntax is a little different looking as it uses an OPENROWSET like follows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://<my-storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<my-container>/<path-to-delta-folder>/',
        FORMAT='DELTA'
    ) AS [recordset];
```

Alternatively, you can create a logical database in the serverless pool and create external tables for each of your delta folders. Doing this would make it seems a little closer to a traditional relational database.

Since this is a serverless instance there is no provisioning costs. You'd only pay for the consumption (e.g. the actual query). You can find the current pay-as-you go pricing here: [Azure Synapse Analytics pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/synapse-analytics/#pricing)

Comment: *A low cost option* - Only if you are happy with 30 second query times as the serverless compute spins up.

Comment: The lowest tier of Synapse analytics shows around 900+ USD Per month plus a lot of convoluted pricing mechanism, Not exactly sure if thats low cost by most standards